# Is the array index or the assigned value evaluated first?

Tags: java, arrays

If I have the following code:

```
array[index] = someValue;
```

does the `someValue` or the `index` get evaluated first?

Comment: @Nambari I could give an example, but it would be rather complicated.

Comment: easy to check by: `array[-1] = someMethodThatPrintsSomething();`

Comment: @alfasin is there a guarantee that it will always behave one way? I can't just test that.

Comment: would you expect the JVM to behave differently every time ? this question doesn't involve any race-condition or anything which has an "unexpected behavior".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The index is evaluated first. See [JLS section 15.26.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1), in particular:

> **15.26.1. Simple Assignment Operator =**
>
> ...
>
> If the left-hand operand is an array access expression (§15.13),
>   possibly enclosed in one or more pairs of parentheses, then:
>
> 1. First, the array reference subexpression of the left-hand operand
>      array access expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes
>      abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the
>      same reason; the index subexpression (of the left-hand operand array
>      access expression) and the right-hand operand are not evaluated and no
>      assignment occurs.
> 2. Otherwise, the index subexpression of the left-hand operand array
>      access expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly,
>      then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason
>      and the right-hand operand is not evaluated and no assignment occurs.
> 3. Otherwise, the right-hand operand is evaluated. If this evaluation
>      completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly
>      for the same reason and no assignment occurs.

**TL;DR**: The order is *1[2]=3*

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the `index` expression is evaluated first.

This test program confirms it:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] array = new int[10];
      array[getIndex()] = getValue();
   }


   private static int getIndex() {
      System.out.println("getIndex!");
      return 0;
   }

   private static int getValue() {
      System.out.println("getValue!");
      return 1;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
getIndex!
getValue!
```

The value is evaluated even if an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown.  Changing `getIndex()`:

```
private static int getIndex() {
   System.out.println("getIndex!");
   return -1;  // Hey!
}
```

Output:

```
getIndex!
getValue!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:90)
```

Comment: The question is, will it do this for every JVM? Is there a guarantee?

Comment: @tbodt Yes every compiler will generate code that behaves this way; the evaluation order is specified in the JLS.

Comment: it's a compiler issue not a JVM issue. from jls `The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.`

Comment: @Downvoter Please explain what is wrong/can be corrected.