# Java ++ or -- : position of increment/decrement operator should be on the left or right of the assignment?

Tags: java, increment

I have the following code:

```
boolean[] myArray = new boolean[10];
int a, b;
       :
myArray[a * b] = myArray[a * b] ? false: true;
a++;
```

I am trying to simplify the following to one line:

```
myArray[a * b] = myArray[a * b] ? false: true;
a++;
```

Should it be:

```
myArray[a * b] = myArray[a++ * b] ? false: true;
```

or

```
myArray[a++ * b] = myArray[a * b] ? false: true;
```

I understand a++ means apply a then do the increment. However, my question here is should a++ be at the left side or right side of the assignment operator "=" ? Thanks!

Comment: Neither. The one-liner versions are much harder to read and debug, even if you get them to do what you want.

Comment: And `b = b ? false : true;` is more concisely written as `b = !b`.

Comment: @Tunaki, I modified the question, this is not really a duplicate. My question is actually should a++ be at right or left of the assignment. Thanks!

Comment: @Edamame Then it is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339242/is-the-array-index-or-the-assigned-value-evaluated-first